# Need better JSON Schema to validate sparse matrix data object

Tags: javascript, validation, jsonschema, ajv

I need to validate complex object in JavaScript.

Object is based on dictionary:

```
var dict = {'1':true,'2':true,'3':true};
```

Object store matrix of pairs (usually not full):

```
var obj = {'1':{
        '1': 'str1',
        '2': 'str2',
        '3': 'str3',
    },'2':{
        '1': 'str1',
        '2': 'str2',
    }
};
```

I make validation schema with AJV validator.

Schema requirements:

1. 1st level object contains only properties from dictionary.
2. 2nd level object contains only properties from dictionary.
3. data is a string

Generating schema:

```js
var dict = {'1':true,'2':true,'3':true};

var subProperties = R.map(function(item){
  return {
    'type' : 'string',
    "minLength": 1,
  }
}, dict);
var root = {
  "type" : "object",
  "additionalProperties" : false
};
root.properties = R.map(function(item){
  return {
    "type" : "object",
    'properties' : subProperties,
    "additionalProperties" : false
  };
}, dict);

console.log(root)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ajv/4.9.0/ajv.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.22.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

This schema is working well but the problem is performance. When dictionary contains 200 elements it requires 10 seconds to compile this schema (validation is fast, compilation is slow). Moreover it throws out of memory exception time to time. Is it possible to make better validation schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memory exceptions are not surprising here given that you are validating 40000 properties. Your validation function code size should be around 30Mb.

You can use propertyNames keyword that I added to [v5/6 proposals](https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/70) and that is available in [ajv-keywords](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv-keywords#propertynames) package.

```
var dict = ['1', '2', '3'];
var schema = {
  type: 'object',
  propertyNames: { enum: dict },
  additionalProperties: {
    type: 'object',
    propertyNames: { enum: dict },
    additionalProperties: {
      type: 'string',
      minLength: 1
    }
  }
};

var ajv = require('ajv')();
require('ajv-keywords')(ajv, 'propertyNames');

var validate = ajv.compile(schema);
```

This schema is tiny but does the same.

You can achieve the same using patternProperties keyword that exists in the current standard version (with es6 property syntax):

```
var names = '^(1|2|3)$';
var schema = {
  type: 'object',
  additionalProperties: false,
  patternProperties: {
    [names]: {
      type: 'object',
      additionalProperties: false,
      patternProperties: {
        [names]: {
          type: 'string',
          minLength: 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

propertyNames looks simpler and should be faster I think.

Comment: Very interesting. Do you have a reference in the specification for `propertyNames`? Even `enum` is all over the examples but looks absent in the [specification](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html).

Comment: First way is good but I don't see the way to add ajv-keywords in browser. Is it possible?
Second way is good too but in fact dictionary contains names of people which can have any symbols. So making regex is possible but unfortunatelly not just arr.join('|').
Also I tried to use "@ref" syntax but compile time doesn't change. Does it mean Ajv compiles the same @ref subschema many times?

Comment: @Hurelu propertyNames is a proposal (see the link), it is available as a custom keyword for ajv, enum is in spec - http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.5.20

Comment: @NtsDK shouldn't be a problem if you use browserify/webpack. All you need is this file really: https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv-keywords/blob/master/keywords/propertyNames.js

Comment: Thank you esp. I used your solution with patternProperties. It reduces compile time from 10 seconds to 1 second. I don't use browserify/webpack so this solution is more suitable for me.

Comment: You can just copy paste the code from the file to add the keyword definition.

Answer (score 1):

By mapping over `items` the result is not `1` but `N` schema (i.e. if you have 200 items, 200 schema get created for the sole purpose of validating the key).

The alternative is to either use `patternProperties` with a huge 200 key long `RegExp` or more simply, just validate the object manually.

```js
var dict = {'1':true,'2':true,'3':true};

var monsterRegex = '^' + Object.keys(dict).join('|') + '$'

var valSchema = {
  type: 'string',
  minLength: 1
}
var keySchema = {
  type: 'object',
  additionalProperties: false,
  patternProperties: {}
}
keySchema.patternProperties[monsterRegex] = valSchema

var objSchema = {
  type: 'object',
  additionalProperties: false,
  patternProperties: {}
}
objSchema.patternProperties[monsterRegex] = keySchema

console.log(objSchema)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ajv/4.9.0/ajv.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This way is good too but in fact dictionary contains names of people which can have any symbols. So making monsterRegex is possible but unfortunatelly not just arr.join('|'). Is it possible to autoescape all regex specials?

Comment: In this case, it is probably simpler to validate your object directly, without JSON schema.